# Error while deploying Node.js App to Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

While deploying my Node.js App on Heroku I am getting the following error.

> 2017-04-18T18:40:10.158442+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> 2017-04-18T18:40:10.158544+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
>
> 2017-04-18T18:40:10.237236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>
> 2017-04-18T18:40:10.230110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>
> 2017-04-18T18:40:29.015395+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nandu-varun-webdev.herokuapp.com request_id=11f3e405-089e-4bef-a83c-f190b042fbb7 fwd="216.15.126.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2017-04-18T18:40:29.282812+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nandu-varun-webdev.herokuapp.com request_id=904f2f85-9c15-4601-bb9a-51a58c7544e1 fwd="216.15.126.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

My package.json file is the following

```
{
  "name": "web-dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Web Dev",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.15",
    "multer":"^1.3.0",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0"

  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "VN",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And my Server.js file is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// configure a public directory to host static content
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

require ("./test/app.js")(app);
require ("./assignment/app.js")(app);
require ("./project/app")(app);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port);
```

Edit: These are the complete logs i am getting

> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.924799+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the web-dev package,
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.925332+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.925449+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs web-dev
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.925583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.925712+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls web-dev
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.925846+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.930287+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.930497+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.930608+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:06.002754+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>
> 2017-04-19T11:38:05.995921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>
> 2017-04-19T14:44:20.909797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nandu-varun-webdev.herokuapp.com request_id=ab500e0f-0137-4b2f-ae8d-fb99c0849597 fwd="216.15.126.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2017-04-19T14:44:21.392032+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nandu-varun-webdev.herokuapp.com request_id=6a277e5f-2329-45d1-82af-4a4cd170e028 fwd="216.15.126.238" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I just cannot figure out what the problem is or why am I unable to deploy successfully.

Any Help would be much appreciated

Thanks In Advance

Comment: These logs ^^ aren't the ones you need. Look further up to the stack trace your app generated when it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

you must create a **Procfile** that contains this :

```
web: npm start
```

did you include it ?

Comment: No I did not how do i do that

Comment: Create the file Procfile that should contain web: npm start. Push it and let's see what happens

Comment: Even though is recommended,there is no need for a Procfile when you only need to run `npm start`. 
By default heroku run `npm start` if a Procfile is not provided, hence probably the cause is something else that is not visible from the logs.

From heroku [procfile documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

*A Procfile is not necessary to deploy apps written in most languages supported by Heroku. The platform automatically detects the language, and creates a default web process type to boot the application server.*